# Why does this throw NullPointerException?

Tags: java

```
e.getCategory() != null ? e.getCategory().getName() : "";
```

This throws a `NullPointerException` and I do not understand why. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Please post a complete stack trace of your NullPointerException. It should help reveal exactly where the problem is occurring.

Comment: Just a tip: in Java, it's generally considered good practice to put a space on either side of most operators, like `!=`, `?` and `:`. It makes code like this much more readable.

Comment: -1 for posting incomplete code, and without the stack trace.

Comment: +1 for doing the best you can and having a positive attitude in the face of commentors using thier "superior" critism skills to not only prvide no helpful insight, but at least some ORIGINAL critisism. -1 to starblue for being a prick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Explanation:

According to Java's precedence rules, your code was being parsed like this:

```
(("\"category\":" + "\"" + e.getCategory()) != null) ? e.getCategory().getName() : ""
```

with the entire concatenation (**`("..." + e.getCategory())`**`!= null`) as the condition.

Since `"..." + e.getCategory()` is never `null`, the code didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

<strike>`e` is `null`.</strike>

Comment: (e.getCategory()!=null) returns false or true and never throws exception

Comment: **Then there is a problem inside of `getName()`.**

Comment: If it is null getName() shouldnt be called...
Until now category wasnt null

Comment: Assuming that this is really the line that caused the exception, and that the first call to getCategory() doesn't return null, there is only one option: getCategory() is not consistent, and returns null in the second call...

Answer (score 1):

Is `e` null?

Perhaps you should try this:

```
(e != null) ?
    (e.getCategory() != null) ?
        e.getCategory().getName() : 
        ""
    : ""
```

Or rather, a simplified form:

```
(e != null && e.getCategory() != null) ?
    e.getCategory().getName() : 
    ""
```

Comment: There is a reason if statements exist... `if(e != null && e.getCategory() != null && ...) ...`

Comment: But trinary expressions are funner! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Solution found....

CORRECT

```
bufo.append("\"category\":" + "\"" + ((e.getCategory() != null) ? e.getCategory().getName() : "") + "\",");
```

PROBLEM

```
bufo.append("\"category\":" + "\"" + e.getCategory()!=null?e.getCategory().getName():"" + "\",");
```

Comment: it seems that it needs ( ) for some reason

Comment: It needs ( ) because otherwise you test the string "category":"null instead of testing the actual reference, which is null. The compiler assumed that you test the result of the string concatenation.

Comment: This makes the case that sometimes it's better to simplify the expression by using a temporary variable. Even if you know the operator precedence rules cold, the next poor slob reading your code may not...

Comment: It looks like the problem version is evaluated as:
`bufo.append(("\"category\":" + "\"" + e.getCategory())!=null?e.getCategory().getName():"" + "\",");`

Comment: Next time, post *at least* the entire line of code that's having the problem. It'll be much easier for others to figure out what's wrong.